# populating 2d array java with char array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, char

how do you transfer a char 1d array into a 2d array and then print the 2d array by reading each column at a time. i.e. use the argument "-encrypt abcd"

```
public class CHARSTRING {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String encrypt = args[0];
    String letters = args[1];
     //length of letters to be encrypted
    int n = letters.length();
    char Rows [] = letters.toCharArray();       

    if (encrypt.equals("-encrypt")) {

        if ( (n*n)/n == n) {

            int RootN = (int) Math.sqrt(n); //find depth and width of 2d array
            char [][] box = new char [RootN][RootN]; //declare 2d array

        for (int i=0; i<RootN; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<RootN; j++) {
                box[i] = Rows;
                System.out.println(Rows);
```

//output is 4 rows of:
abcd

but im trying to get the output to be "acbd"

Comment: so you want the output to be abcd for the first row?

Answer (score 0):

In your double loop at the end, you have one loop for rows, and one for columns. Don't use :

```
    for (int i=0; i<RootN; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<RootN; j++) {
            box[i] = Rows;
            System.out.println(Rows);
        }
    }
```

That prints every value of Rows with println, so it adds a "\n" after each line. Instead, try using :

```
    for (int i=0; i<RootN; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<RootN; j++) {
            box[i] = Rows;
            System.out.print(Rows);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This way, all values should be printed on the same line, and after that change for a new line.